# Changing the colors of individual lines of a dataarray.plot.lines faceting plot

Tags: matplotlib, python-xarray, facet

Hi I'm doing a facet plot of a dataarray where I have multiple timelines across different dimensions of the array. Right now I'm able to plot them like in the image below, but I want to define/change the color for the individual timelines ('raw', 'rol', 'fh' ...) I can only set one color for all the timelines in each plot by adding the argument color = 'green' to the .plot.lines() command, but not separatly for each of them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
    
    scatsurface=scat.loc[:,:,:,"st"]
    t=scatsurface.plot.line(x="time", col="Latitude", col_wrap=3, size =8)
        
    for i, ax in enumerate(t.axes.flat):
                                         
        plt.ylim(-15, 15)
        ax.set_xlabel('')
                            
        if i==0:
            ax.set_title('Antarctic')
            ax.set_ylabel('Temperature 2 m')
            plt.grid(True)
        if i==1:
            ax.set_title('Arctic')
            plt.grid(True)
        if i==2:
            ax.set_title('Tropics')
            plt.grid(True)
```

[the dataarray I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgNkd.png)

[The plots I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00J4j.png)

Comment: you can modify the color cycler - https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html

Comment: also, please don't upload images of data - instead just copy the outputs of `print(da)` and paste as code, or better yet, create a [mre]. thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will definitely do so next time.